# SQL Server blob data deletion taking time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables. There is a delete trigger on table 1 which will delete the data from the other 2 tables. There is an `image` column in tables 2 & 3.

All 3 tables have 1400 rows. Now read following and let me have the suggestions or solutions on this.

1. The delete trigger I mentioned above has delete statements for tables 2 & 3. And now if I execute a `delete` statement on table 1, it takes 5 minutes for the delete operation to complete
2. I commented out the `delete` statements for table 2 & 3 in trigger I mentioned above. And now if I execute a `delete` statement on table 1, it takes 22 seconds to complete

So it's pretty straight forward that blobs are taking a lot of time to be deleted. Can we improve performance in case 1?

Comment: The `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: What does your execution plan say? How many rows are you deleting from table 1? And what is the relationship between tables 1-2-3? Is it **Table1** -> 1:M - **Table2** -> 1:M -> **Table3**?

Comment: The question is more on blob data deletion.

@marc_s: I understand. right now we can not do this.

Radu: as mentioned in the question, all 3 tables are having 1400 rows. And the relation is as mentioned by you.

Note: Blob data exists in the Tables 2 & 3, of type image.